# How to use LIKE Keyword in sql scratch pad within EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I would like to get an object from t_object if its keyword contains word **"Test"** . Even if has "**Testing" or "Tested"** i need to get that data rom row .

In sql we can use LIKE keyword. But how to use it inside EA SQL Scratch Pad ..?

```
SELECT * FROM t_object where t_object.PDATA5 like '%Test%'
```

The above is not working within EA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the RDBMS. If you use EAP the wild card is `*`. Most others use `%`. But Mickeysoft always implements its own flavors.

(See also chap. 13 of my Inside book.)